# django middleware difference between process_request and process_view

Tags: django, middleware

I am little bit confused on `process_request` and `process_view`.

Process request is something that u want to pass on view with request. Example can be taken from `request.user`.

Then what does `process_view` does ? Is it for executing any view initially befor calling any url ? Like initially I want to show home view but this can be done from url too.

Can anyone give me example when to use `process_view` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 35):

[`process_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) is called before Django determines which view should handle the request (hence, its only parameter is the `request`).

[`process_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view) is called after Django determines which view will handle the request, but before that view is called. It will have access to the `request` object, along with the view that will handle it and the parameters that will be passed to that view.

Whenever you need to know the view that will be used for a request, you can use `process_view`. A good example for this is [Django's CSRF Middleware `process_view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py), which will not enforce CSRF protection if a csrf_exempt decorator is present on the view the request is meant for:

```
def process_view(self, request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs):
    [...]

    if getattr(callback, 'csrf_exempt', False):
       return None

    [...]
```

Answer (score 11):

Adrian Ghiuta have written a very good answer. I just want to add few points to that.

`process_request` is called before doing the url matching and `process_view` is called after url matching but before invoking that view.

We can use the `process_request` to change the url itself and thus invoke a different view. This point helped me understand these, so I thought to answer it, maybe it'll someone else too.